# пунктуация, стилистика

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Здравствуйте, подскажите, где в данном случае нужны запятые? Также(?) при покупке в сети "Золотое яблоко" можно получить подвеску в подарок в нашем ювелирном торговом центре "Голден парк"(?) по адресу Щорса, 29!

На мой взгляд, само предложение коряво построено.

Comment: Щорса, 29? Знакомые места, в получасе ходьбы. (0:

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Также при покупке товаров в сети "Золотое яблоко" вы можете получить  в подарок подвеску  в нашем ювелирном торговом центре "Голден парк" по адресу ул. Щорса, 29!